# Understanding compute acquisition times across pipelines

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am struggling to optimize my data factory pipeline to achieve as little time spent in spinning up compute for dataflows.

My understanding is that if we set up a runtime with a TTL of say 15 minutes, then all subsequent flows executed in a sequence following this should experience very short compute acquisition times, but does this also hold true, when switching from one pipeline to the other - in the image below, would flow 3 utilize that the runtime was already spun up in flow 1? I ask because I see very sporadic behavior.

[Pipeline example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuPPl.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the same Azure IR inside of the same factory, yes. However, the activities must be executed sequentially, otherwise, ADF will spin-up another pool for you. That's because Databricks parallel job executions are not supported in job clusters. I describe the techniques in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VT_2ZV3a7Fc) and in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-overview#azure-integration-runtime-and-data-flow-strategies).